# Psycopg2 with Python 3.7 and 3.8 - missing libssl.1.1.dylib

Tags: python, psycopg2

Newly updated to macOS Catalina. New install of python 3.7 (was 3.8).

I did run the 'Install Certificates.command' suggested by the python installer.

pip3 used to install psycopg2, pyYAML etc.

I cannot import psycopg2 - missing libssl.1.1.dylib

I checked in /usr/lib and found a bunch of libssl..., but not the one that psycopg2 is looking for:

```
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.35.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.43.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.44.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.46.dylib
/usr/lib/libssl.dylib
```

I tried 'brew install openssl' but it was not the correct version.

Is pip supposed to download the required dependencies for psycopg2 ?  If not, how/where do I get the correct ssl library ?

UPDATE: The file is there, in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
/Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
/Library/edb/languagepack/v1/Python-3.7/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
```

I don't know why it cannot be found.

Is this maybe something to do with security changes in Catalina ?

Comment: Python 3.8 is very new version - maybe install 3.7 and wait few months till 3.8 will be better tested.

Comment: Same issue with 3.7. The library is there, not sure why iy cannot find it. /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib

Comment: Ever figured it out? I am having this issue.

Comment: From my notes:     PostgreSQL:
    -----------
    1.  Install Postgres (EDB Version).
    2.  Put /Library/PostgreSQL/<version>/bin on the path in .bash_profile and .bashrc then open terminal.
    3.  To use psycopg2 to access PostgreSQL:
          pip3 install psycopg2
          then pip3 install psycopg2-binary
This works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I got help from the Apple Community.

With the latest(?) psycopg, the binary is required.

```
pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

solved this issue for me.